# Confirm ARHit Ready

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit

I am using Unity with Apples's ARKitHitTest script. I have created a prompt on the UI that asks the user to point at the ground and scan.

What I am trying to do is determine when the ARKit has enough points scanned to place target. Once I figured out how this is done I can then update the user Prompt to say ready to place. Can anyone please advise how I determine when ARKit is ready to place? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARKit has a number of methods which you can utilise to determine whether tracking is available, and whether for example conditions are not ideal for tracking.

These can be obtained in `Unity` by registering for the following callbacks:

```
UnityARSessionNativeInterface.ARFrameUpdatedEvent += ARFrameUpdated;
UnityARSessionNativeInterface.ARSessionFailedEvent += ARSessionFailedEvent;
```

These can help you to determine whether tracking is available or limited for example.

Essentially when a Session has good conditions e.g the delegate informs us that:

```
ARTrackingStateReason.ARTrackingStateReasonNone
```

We know that conditions are suitable for placing an object, as enough featurePoints are available etc.

As such a Class to handle this might look like so:

```
public class ARTrackingStatusController : MonoBehaviour {

    //1. Get Reference To The Session
    private UnityARSessionNativeInterface augmentedRealitySession;


    private string arTrackingStatus = "Preparing Device...";


    //------------------
    //MARK: -  LifeCycle
    //------------------

    void Start () {

        //1. Register For The ARFrame Updated Event Which In IOS = (func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval))
        UnityARSessionNativeInterface.ARFrameUpdatedEvent += ARFrameUpdated;
        UnityARSessionNativeInterface.ARSessionFailedEvent += ARSessionFailedEvent;


    }

    void Update () {

        //1. Update The Status Of The Session
        print(arTrackingStatus);

    }


    //-------------------------
    //MARK: - ARSCNViewDelegate
    //-------------------------

    /// <summary>
    /// Called Each Time The ARCamera Is Updated
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="camera">Camera.</param>
    public void ARFrameUpdated (UnityARCamera camera)
    {

        //1. Track The ARSession
        if (camera.trackingState == ARTrackingState.ARTrackingStateLimited) {

            logTrackingStateReason (camera.trackingReason);

        } else {

            logTrackingState (camera.trackingState);

        }

        logLighting (camera.lightData.arLightEstimate.ambientIntensity);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Logs The ARSession Failed Event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="error">Error.</param>
    public void ARSessionFailedEvent (string error)
    {

        print (error);

    }

    //----------------------
    //MARK: - Status Updates
    //----------------------

    /// <summary>
    /// Informs The User About The Current Tracking State
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="trackingState">Tracking state.</param>
    public void logTrackingState (ARTrackingState trackingState)
    {

        switch (trackingState) {

        case ARTrackingState.ARTrackingStateNormal:
            arTrackingStatus = "Tracking Ready";

            break;

        case ARTrackingState.ARTrackingStateNotAvailable:
            arTrackingStatus = "Tracking Unavailable";
            break;

        }


    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Informs The User About The Current Tracking Status
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="reason">Reason.</param>
    public void logTrackingStateReason (ARTrackingStateReason reason)
    {

        switch (reason) {

        case ARTrackingStateReason.ARTrackingStateReasonExcessiveMotion:
            arTrackingStatus = "Please Slow Your Movement";
            break;

        case ARTrackingStateReason.ARTrackingStateReasonInsufficientFeatures:
            arTrackingStatus = "Try To Point At A Flat Surface";
            break;

        case ARTrackingStateReason.ARTrackingStateReasonInitializing:
            arTrackingStatus = "Initializing";
            break;

        case ARTrackingStateReason.ARTrackingStateReasonRelocalizing:
            arTrackingStatus = "Relocalizing";
            break;

        case ARTrackingStateReason.ARTrackingStateReasonNone:
            arTrackingStatus = "";
            break;

        }


    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines If The Current Lighting Conditions Are Appropriate For The ARSession
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="lightEstimate">Light estimate.</param>
    public void logLighting (float lightEstimate)
    {

        if (lightEstimate < 100) {
            arTrackingStatus = "Lighting Is To Dark";

        }

    }
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: You could not have made it more clearer! Perfect solution. Thanks so much (sorry for delay responding)